# Pass DGV selected rows to 2nd form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to pass selected rows of a datagridview to a second form.  Then select items in a second DGV and pass the information into a table at that point.  What I was trying to do is pass the rows in the manner below:
Form1:

```
private void toolStripLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int interestsKey;
        interestsKey = Convert.ToInt32(interestsKeyTextBox.Text);

        DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows = interestAddDataGridView.SelectedRows;

        frmDupeAdd AddDupeForm = new frmDupeAdd(interestAddDataGridView.SelectedRows);
        AddDupeForm.Show();
    }
```

On form 2 I cannot seem to be able to access dgIntRows.  Not sure if this is the correct way to do this or if there is a better way.

Form 2:

```
 public frmDupeAdd(DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection selectedRows)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection dgIntRows = selectedRows;
        }

  private void btnAddAdds_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows = dgCaseInt.SelectedRows;
            dgCaseInt.Columns[4].Visible = false;
            dgCaseInt.Columns[5].Visible = false;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
            {

                DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                int interestkeyint  = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[4].Value);
                InterestAdd newinterestadd = new InterestAdd();
                newinterestadd.InterestsKey = interestkeyint;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgIntRows)
                {
                    newinterestadd.CaseNumberKey = (string)row.Cells[5].Value; ;
                    newinterestadd.streetNum = (string)row.Cells[2].Value;
                    newinterestadd.Direction = (string)row.Cells[2].Value;
                    newinterestadd.Add1 = (string)row.Cells[3].Value;
                    newinterestadd.Suffix = (string)row.Cells[4].Value;
                    newinterestadd.Unit = (string)row.Cells[5].Value;
                    newinterestadd.City = (string)row.Cells[6].Value;
                    newinterestadd.State = (string)row.Cells[7].Value;
                    newinterestadd.Zip = (string)row.Cells[8].Value;
                    db.InterestAdds.InsertOnSubmit(newinterestadd);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }


            }


        }
```

Comment: You're declaring `dgIntRows` in the constructor. When the constructor finishes that variable leaves scope. Declare it as a `private` field in your class and assign to it in the constructor, and other methods can access it.

Comment: Technically more appealing approach would be to avoid passing form specific data around, but to have data provider which is used by both forms. It can then be used to pass or even automatically synchronize items selection in both forms.

Comment: @Sinatr what do you mean by that?  The data provider is used by both forms.  What I have is a form with a DGV that the user adds addresses to and I want to be able to select one or more of those addresses, hit the button and select other interests from that case and add the addresses that were selected to those selected interests.  Then there will be a follow up later that will allow a user to type in an interest name, find the addresses associated with that name and add those addresses to the current record / interest.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
public frmDupeAdd(DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection selectedRows)
 {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection dgIntRows = selectedRows;
 }
```

use

```
private DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection dgIntRows = new DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection ()
    public frmDupeAdd(DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection selectedRows)
         {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    dgIntRows = selectedRows;
         }
```